# How to connect to mysql using ipv6 from wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL host that only expose an IPv6 address from Wordpress running in [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/). I try to add the IP to the host like this:

```
$ docker run --name some-wordpress -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=<my_ipv6_addr> \
    -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=... -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=... -d wordpress
```

Where `<my_ipv6_addr` is the IPv6 address to the MySQL host. But wordpress fails to connect with the following error message:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Invalid argument in - on line 10
```

Is there a way to connect Wordpress to MySQL in Docker using IPv6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your [docker daemon is running with the `--ipv6` flag](http://docs.docker.com/v1.5/articles/networking/#ipv6)

> By default, the Docker server configures the container network for IPv4 only.
>   You can enable IPv4/IPv6 dualstack support by running the Docker daemon with the `--ipv6` flag. Docker will set up the bridge docker0 with the IPv6 link-local address `fe80::1`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually using Kubernetes in GKE so my hope was that this would be possible without daemon "modifications". But I suppose that's another question.

Comment: @Johan Indeed. It might have been useful to include that tidbit in the question.

Comment: I've added a follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736833/how-to-connect-to-ipv6-addresses-in-kubernetes-running-on-google-container-engin