# How to connect to IPv6 addresses in Kubernetes running on Google Container Engine?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ipv6, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

**Background**
I'd like to connect [Wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) docker container to a Google Could SQL instance. By default Google Cloud SQL only expose an IPv6 address and preferably I'd like to connect Wordpress to this address but I can't find a way to do so (see my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33733279/how-to-connect-to-mysql-using-ipv6-from-wordpress/) stackoverflow post for details).

**Question**

I'd like to know if it's possible to connect to an IPv6 address from a pod running in Kubernetes (GKE)? If so how?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/1443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Google Cloud Platform [Networks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking?hl=en#networks) only support IPv4, so connecting to IPv6 addresses from GKE is not possible.

Comment: Have there been any updates on this by any chance? Anything within GCS other than waiting on Kubernetes for it? https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/1443